# Jackson Mapper: Unable to convert JSON object to Java Singleton class

Tags: java, json, rest, jackson

I have a JSON data which is passed via a REST WebService:

```
"dimension": {
    "@type": "com.example.multi.MultiDimension",
    "listId": "tempListId1",
    "key": "PERN",
    "displayName": "Personal"
  }
```

Now, MultiDimension is a Singleton class, i.e. having a **private** constructor.
So Jackson was not able to find the the public constructor and was giving parsing error.

```
No suitable constructor found for type [simple type, class com.example.multi.MultiDimension]: can not instantiate from JSON object (need to add/enable type information?)\n at [Source: org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination$1@404e8aba; line: 8, column: 9]
```

Well, then I added a **public** constructor in MultiDimension class and as expected it worked.

My concern is that from Singleton class I made it open, is their any way where I can still have a Singleton Class and Jackson Mapper can map the class specifying the method name i.e. `getInstance()` from the class

Comment: as i remember you need empty contractor not private

Comment: You can use `@JsonCreator` on your `getInstance()` method.

Comment: Aren't you thinking something wrong here? Incoming data that is supposed to be deserialized into an object should not be read into a singleton. I have it hard to see a reasonable use case.

If I would want the stuff to be passed into the singleton I would first deserialize this to a data transfer object that is then input into the singleton as relevant to the scope.

Comment: The next incoming package on the REST web service would overwrite the results of the first package.

Comment: @dambros: I have a parameterised constructor `public static MultiDimension getInstance(String key)` how can I pass the parameter, I found nothing on that.

Answer (score 1):

you can use @jsonCreator and paramtere can be passed like this.

```
@JsonCreator
public static MultiDimension getInstance(@JsonProperty("key") String key) {...}
```